# Аналог ng serve для верстки

Tags: angular2

Есть ли npm пакет для верстки, такой как у Angular 2 (ng serve). Запускаешь и он сам обновляется в браузере и показывает.

Comment: В angular'е это, кажется, сделано с помощью [webpack'а](https://webpack.github.io/). Также существуют расширения к редакторам (например, [LIve Edit для WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-edit.html))

Comment: В `sublime text` есть `Live reload`. Обновляет страницу после сохранения изменений из `sublime`.